# How do I return custom response/status code in Django?

Tags: django, http, http-status-codes, status

I want to return status code different from `100 <= self.status_code <= 599`, as written in Django's  [HttpResponseBase](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5ea1621c724e765c9a642a1b3b6e83419fda920b/django/http/response.py#L29) class. Is there are any easy way to bypass this restriction?

Comment: The HTTP codes have ranges, for example 100-199 is information, 200-299 is success, 300-399 redirection, etc. So it does not make much sense to return a status code outside this range. Especially since a browser will typically for example redirect in case of a 301/302.

Answer (score 9):

You can, if you really want, patch the `.status_code` attribute. For example with:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse('some data')
    response.status_code = 754  # sample status code
    return response
```

But it does not make much sense to specify a [HTTP status code [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) outside the 100-599 range, since these are subdivided into subranges that specify in what case to return what status code.